# The number of words containing four $a$'s and two $b$'s

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of words containing four $a$'s and two $b$'s.

I thought of $6!$ but then I found out that there will be many repetitions in that case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are $6$ "slots" for the letters. We must **choose** $2$ slots to put the b's into.

Comment: It's like choosing where you put the letters $b$. You have $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have 6! posibilities if all the "a"s where different. As long as each "a" is interchangeable with any other you have to divide between the number of combinations you can make with them (which is 4!). Same deal with the "b"s.

The result will be 6! / (4! * 2!) = 15

Answer (score 0):

Try listing them. There are only 15. Think of this pattern: x a x a x a x a x. You can replace any x by bb. That is 5 possibilities. Or you can replace each of two x by an a. That is 5-choose-2 or 10 possibilities. Total 15.

Comment: That's quite the scenic route to that result, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

We have six positions to fill.  Notice that a particular arrangement is completely determined by which four of the positions are filled by $a$'s or, alternatively, which two of the positions are filled by $b$'s.  Hence, the number of distinguishable arrangements of four $a$'s and two $b$'s is 
$$\binom{6}{4} = \binom{6}{2} = 15$$

Note that $6!$ is the number of ways of arranging six distinct objects in order.